# Show that the probability that (U,V) belongs to D equals the probability that (X,Y) belongs to D' where D' is a domain related to D

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, vectors, normal-distribution

**Prompt:**

I have two random variables X and X, with joint density f(x,y).

Then I know that X and Y are independent normal random variables with density f(x) = $(2\pi)^{-1/2}e^{\frac{-x^{2}}{2}}$

I have a $U = \vec{u} \cdot(X,Y)$ and $V=\vec{v} \cdot (X,Y)$ and $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ are orthogonal vectors.

And then D a subset of $R^2$

**What I did:**
I honestly have no clue where to go with this, I know that the probability that (X,Y) belongs to a subset D of $R^2$ is the integral of f over D. So i imagine that i have to take $\int_{\infty}^{\infty}(2\pi)^{-1/2}e^{\frac{-x^{2}}{2}}dx$ But I think that's a really complicated integral to deal with. How am I supposed to go about this?

Comment: You have to assume that $u$ and $v$ are orthonormal. Just orthogonality is not enough.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Assuming that u and v are orthonormal, how would you about this next? Is my intuition to integrate f over D correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Let $\vec u=(u_1,u_2)$ and $\vec v=(v_1,v_2)$ Then $U=u_1X+u_2Y\sim N(0,1)$ and $V=v_1X+v_2Y\sim N(0,1)$. Also, $E[UV]=E[(u_1X+u_2Y)(v_1X+v_2Y)]=u_1v_1+u_2v_2=0$. Since $(U,V)$ is jointly normal with covariance $0$ they are independent. It follows that the joint distribution of $(U,V)$ is same as that of $(X,Y)$.

An alternative method which does not use properties of jointly normal r.v.'s uses just the transformation formula in two dimensions.